# XCode add a build rule to run a method on all files of a certain type

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to have xcode run an objective-c project on all of my .idl files before it builds the rest of the project, where the separate project takes the idl file as an arg. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "run an objective-c method"? Easily a shell script, run as a build step, could solve your problem. More info please.

Comment: You'll need to create a separate executable including that Objective-C method and call that (from within a script) as part of the build.

Comment: yeah I phrased that poorly. I have another objective C project that parses .idl files and builds a .h from them so i can hand wavy simulate Microsoft COM. I want to have a shell script call that project with the file name as an arg but I'm not sure how to get the file name for the arg. would I just do
for *.idl
 gcc -framework Foundation parser.m -o parser Compile parser.m & call it parser *.idl

?